# install cwm recovery in a softbrick android phone

Tags: recovery-mode, rom, unbricking, device-firmware, unrooting

My Android device is not booting up and is stuck on the manufacturer's logo.  The phone was rooted with Kingo-Root and Clockwork Recovery Mod wasn't installed.  Now I want to unbrick my phone with custom rom flashing.  So I think I need to install CWM recovery although my device is not booting - is this possible?  Also, if I want to flash a stock ROM - do I need to unroot my device first?  If so, how can I unroot it if it's not booting?

Comment: Please include info about your device and android version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go ahead with what you are planning. Find a suitable Clockwork Mod recovery for your device.

Boot your phone into fastboot mode using key combinations which differ from device to device. The common ones are Power Button+Volume Up or Power Button+Volume Down.

If you had ever unlocked your device's bootloader, skip this step. To flash a custom recovery, you need your bootloader to be unlocked. To unlock it, after booting the phone into fastboot mode, connect it with PC via USB, download platform tools for android, open cmd, run the following command in the directory where you have placed the platform tools:

```
fastboot oem unlock
```

Keep in mind, this will delete all your internal storage, plus void your phone's warranty.

Once the bootloader is unlocked, place the recovery file in the platform tools directory and rename it to recovery.img for convenience.

Run the command:

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

This will flash the Clockwork Mod recovery on your device and you can flash any desirable ROM.

Comment: my phone does not boot into fastboot mode.it can boot into download mode and can install apk from google play.and also can boot into Stock recovery.In any mode,the  command  "fastboot devices" shows nothing.

Comment: The command "fastboot devices" will not show any result until and unless you're in fastboot mode. Which phone is it?

Comment: walton primo e2.

Comment: Some Google search suggests your phone uses the MT6572 CPU. That's the same as my phone. The combination I use to get into bootloader is Volume Up + Power Up and that shows me a set of options: Fastboot mode, recovery mode and normal boot. I select fastboot mode from there. You may try this method..

Comment: thanks for trying to solve my problem.But my phone doesn't show those option.However my phone come to life after flushing stock rom from android xda with sptools.But it has no sound and cannot detect sd card.how can i solve it?

Comment: That can be a problem with your ROM. I'm not sure on this though. Now that your phone is booting, you can easily install custom recovery. Download MobileUncle MTK Tools app from Play store, download the CWM recovery.img for your device, copy it in your internal memory, and flash it using MobileUncle tools app (this app requires root access).

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a samsung device go into the download mode 
-> *continue* 
install odin on ur pc and download the stock rom for your device 
open odin 
now connect your device
you will see com1 highlighted *that means your phone is connected* and select the files .
**Note: Do not change any settings .**
finally click on start after completing the process your phone will automatically rebooot .
*Enjoy...*